# Determining if Excel cell contains array formula or text value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a big table where one column contains a formula each row (an array formula, to be specific), which returns with a string.
But some of the formulas are overwritten with a similar string value.

I would like to create a conditional formatting to color the cells which are overwritten.

How can I create a formula to determine if the cell contains an array formula or a simple text value?

I have already tried `=CELL("type", A2)`, but it returned "l" even if the cell contained a formula.

Comment: http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip045.htm

Comment: Excel 2013 introduced the [ISFORMULA function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ISFORMULA-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5) if that is relevant to your particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully the function `FORMULATEXT` does just that in the 2013 version of Excel.

It sounds like you want to determine if there is or is not a formula vice return the text so I would recommend adding an `IFNA` function as well like the example below.

```
=IFNA(FORMULATEXT(A1),"No Formula")
```

You could even take that one step further with an IF statement around that.

```
=IF(IFNA(FORMULATEXT(A1),"No Formula")="No Formula","This is simple text","This is a formula")
```

Check out Bill Jelean's podcast on doing this in previous versions of Excel.

[Learn Excel 2010 - "=FORMULA TEXT() in Excel 2010": Podcast #1691](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpRGTvhp1cY)

Comment: Wouldn't the XL2013 [ISFORMULA function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ISFORMULA-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) cut that `IF` criteria down a bit?

Comment: Yes... Yes it absolutely would.